# Extracting data from JSON with ASP.Net web service

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I am trying unsuccessfully to extract the formatted_address property.

The following web service logs the JSON below to the console. I cannot get the formatted address using `returnedData.d.results[0].formatted_address`.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ReportIncident.aspx/ReverseGeocode",
        data: "{latitude:" + latitude + ",longitude:" + longitude + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (returnedData)
        {
          console.log(returnedData);
        }
    });
```

The format of the json is the exact same as the format over [here at Google](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true).

**Edit**
Darin pointed out that I was contradicting myself: the web service wraps up everything in the link above in a d object, I failed to mention that.

[image]

**Further edit**
Here is the web service:

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string ReverseGeocode(decimal latitude, decimal longitude)
        {
            // Create the web request  

            string url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + latitude + "," + longitude +"&sensor=true";
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

            // Get response  
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                // Get the response stream  
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```

and here is the javascript:

```
/Gets the current location of the user
function getLocation()
{
    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }

}

function showPosition(position)
{
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ReportIncident.aspx/ReverseGeocode",
        data: "{latitude:" + latitude + ",longitude:" + longitude + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (returnedData)
        {
            alert(returnedData.d[0].results[0].formatted_address);
            console.log(returnedData);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure that there is a `.d` property in the result?

Comment: yes, it is an ASP.Net web service: see http://encosia.com/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/

Comment: I know this. It's just that you are contradicting yourself in the question when you are saying that the JSON looks exactly the same as the link you have shown. So are you getting an error when you try to access `returnedData.d.results[0].formatted_address`?

Comment: What error are you getting in your console?

Comment: @Tamil If i use returnedData.d.results, I then get a results is 'undefined' error

Comment: in your console image "d" is not a property of returnedData so:
try d.results[0].formatted_address

Comment: where do you assign the Json to "D"?

Comment: I'm sorry for d[0] I didn't try maximizing the image :( Can you put up the console log of `typeof(returnedData.d)` and typeof(returnedData.d.results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this issue turns out to be that the web service is returning a string, instead of json. The built-in javascript serializer does not get used. The eval keyword or something more secure needs to be used. As it happens I ended up using the Google Maps Javascript API and that was much easier anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `returnedData.results[0].formatted_address` without the `.d.` node. That does not exist!

Answer (score 0):

remove the ".d"

```
returnedData.results[0].formatted_address
```

but doing this you are always getting the first node only

Comment: what do you get if you do :
`console.log(returnedData.d);` ?